# ¿Cómo cargar todas las imágenes del dispositivo en Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

Estoy trabajando en un app donde necesito obtener todas las imágenes del dispositivo. Ya logré obtener todas las imágenes. Pero el problema está a la hora de mostrar todas las imágenes al usuario. Coloco las imágenes en un Gridview y todo funciona aparentemente bien. Pero cuando hago scroll en el Gridview la aplicación se cierra. Imagino que sea por la cantidad de imágenes que esta utilizando, que actualmente ronda las 1400 imágenes.
El paquete que utilizo para obtener todas las imágenes es image_gallery https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery
¿Cómo podría solucional esto? Gracias.

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List _allImage = new  List();
  List _allNameList = new List();


  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold (
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Row (
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Gallery ${_allImage.length} imagenes'),
            Expanded(child: Container(),),
            IconButton (
              onPressed: () {
                //TODO Buscar
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
          ],
        ),

      ),
      body: _imagesGrid(columnCount: 3)
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadImageList();
  }

  _imagesGrid({int columnCount}) {
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      itemCount: _allImage.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: columnCount,
        crossAxisSpacing: 10,
        mainAxisSpacing: 10
      ),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          child: Image (
            filterQuality: FilterQuality.none,
            image: Image.file(File(_allImage[index].toString())).image,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _loadImageList() async {
    Map<dynamic, dynamic>  allImageTemp;
    allImageTemp = await FlutterGallaryPlugin.getAllImages;
    setState(() {
      this._allImage = allImageTemp['URIList'] as List;
      this._allNameList = allImageTemp['DISPLAY_NAME'] as List;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste por favor, saludos

Comment: Hola. Ya logré obtener todas las imágenes. El problema ahora es que como son muchas imágenes parece que la RAM se llena y se cierra la app cuando bajo en el GridView.

Comment: Gracias. Ya pude lograrlo utilizando el paquete https://pub.dev/packages/media_gallery

Comment: hola me puedes decir como implementaste ese package? intente hacerlo pero no lo logre!

Comment: Hola. Al final entre una cosa y la otra termine utilizando este paquete https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager. Que me funcionó bien.